# Regex in S3 input plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I neeed to get prefix in S3 input by using Regex, but there is no support for Regex in the doc.

Folders list like this:

```
logs/20180304/app1/app1.log
logs/23180304/app2/app2.log
logs/20180305/app1/app1.log
logs/23180305/app2/app2.log
logs/20180306/app1/app1.log
logs/23180306/app2/app2.log
```

my input plugin in Logstash

```
  s3
       {
         access_key_id => "ABDCWERJKPOKJVB"
         secret_access_key => "4356ytghnfvgbh09oiujsedfvgh0piod"
         region => "as-sfg-2"
         bucket => "new-logs"
         prefix => "log/*/app1/app1.log
       }
 s3
       {
         access_key_id => "ABDCWERJKPOKJVB"
         secret_access_key => "4356ytghnfvgbh09oiujsedfvgh0piod"
         region => "as-sfg-2"
         bucket => "new-logs"
         prefix => "log/*/app1/app2.log
       }
```

I tried the above prefix but logstash not getting the logs from those prefixes